# Why can't we install the bulk of visual studio 2019 on non system drive?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

Installing frameworks and everything seems to be heavy on system drive. I wonder why.

I got 4 TB on drive D and only 256 GB on drive C. So I prefer non system drive.

There is a field to change location of installed things. But those are greyed out

[image]

Should I uninstall and reinstall the whole thing?

Update: I can change the shared Installed Directory. Drive C still get the bulk of the installation though

I am following the instruction https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258937/cannot-change-directory-of-shared-components-tools.html to change the installation location

[image]

Update:

It must be bugs. The location is clearly on drive D and the total amount of installation is 21.8 GB is clearly located on drive D. However, somehow the installer says it'll be in drive C

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Under **Install Locations** in [setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-7---change-the-installation-location-optional), you can change the folders:

[image]

> You can reduce the installation footprint of Visual Studio on your
>   system drive. You can choose to move the download cache, shared
>   components, SDKs, and tools to different drives, and keep Visual
>   Studio on the drive that runs it the fastest.

Comment: That's precisely the problem. I can't change the location of the shared components and tools and sdk.

Answer (score -2):

I just want to add that magicandre1981 is right.

If you have installed VS before then the option is greyed out.

What you need to do in such cases is

1. Uninstall visual studio
2. Use this to really uninstall https://www.totaluninstaller.com/program-uninstall-center/can-totally-remove-microsoft-visual-studio/
3. Go to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258937/cannot-change-directory-of-shared-components-tools.html . Delete some registry

I basically deleted all registry entry in

You can change directory in registry at path "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio"

There is also a software that will not only uninstall visual studio but all the components. I forget where to find it. You should manually delete those too.

Reinstall.

Change all the drive.